# Where to nest trim into a google sheet formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, trim, regexp-replace

I am stuck trying to find how to put trim into a function to remove blank answers from a query on a column of cells

=IFERROR(INDEX(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(N3&" ","\D+"," ")," "))=11,
SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(N3&" ","\D+"," ")," "),"")),"where Col1 is not null ",0))),"")

got me to extract the numbers from a mix of numbers and letters in a list but has left

| Column A |
| --- |
| 12345678912 |
|  |
|  |
|  |
|  |
|  |
|  |
|  |
| 12345678912 |

id like for it to pull up and end up like

| Column A |
| --- |
| 12345678912 |
| 12345678912 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(N:N, LEN(N:N)=11, NOT(ISDATE_STRICT(N:N)))
```

[image]

Comment: no luck unfortunately, still gives out the same input, am i not entering it correctly?should i apply it as an array formula or rearrange the formula at all? thank you for your help.  you can use this link for the list of reference.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74199593/google-sheets-transpose-irregular-column-data-in-groups-into-rows

Comment: @Nickm can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Comment: its the table from the link i posted and im trying to pull the number after company ex 70000123456, 70000987654

Comment: @Nickm updated, try now

Comment: worked, much better than anything i've tried, thank you